# C# Selenium access browser log

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium

Is there a way of capturing browser logs in c# using selenium.

I am looking to capture any JS errors that appear on a particular page. Preferable on Chrome or Firefox.

I have previously done this in Python but can this be done in C#?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To set-up and retrieve the log entries with Selenium / Chrome / C# :

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.SetLoggingPreference(LogType.Browser, LogLevel.Warning);

var driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://stackoverflow.com");

var entries = driver.Manage().Logs.GetLog(LogType.Browser);
foreach (var entry in entries) {
    Console.WriteLine(entry.ToString());
}
```

And with Firefox:

```
FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
options.SetLoggingPreference(LogType.Browser, LogLevel.Warning);

var driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);

driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://stackoverflow.com");

var entries = driver.Manage().Logs.GetLog(LogType.Browser);
foreach (var entry in entries) {
    Console.WriteLine(entry.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Great Help. Solved my Issue. Many Thanks

Comment: Throws NullReferenceException with the latest chromedriver now :(

Comment: This solution doesn't work.  NullRef exception because driver.Manage().Logs is null no matter what.

Comment: The current stable release version of the `Selenium.WebDriver` nuget package (v3.141.0 or lower) is incompatible with Google Chrome 76 or higher in this area (non-W3C recommendation compliant logging methods). I just tried the latest alpha version of the nuget package (4.0.0-alpha04) - I get no logs but at least `GetLog()` no longer throws the NRE. This commit should have fixed it: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/commit/26d8b67a58e99fa4121376537ea434c761eea5e6

Comment: This successfully gets console logs for me with nuget package 4.0.0-alpha05. It does not work with 3.141.0.

Comment: @crouleau I'm still getting this with 4.0.0-alpha05 :(

Answer (score 0):

This library can help you with that: [JSErrorCollector](https://github.com/halad/JSErrorCollector.NET).

When you're using it you just have to write one line to get all the errors listed:

```
List<JavaScriptError> jsErrors = JavaScriptError.ReadErrors(driver);
```

Comment: Link yields 404