# Get client-side logs in Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium

I'm using Selenium in C# and would like to read the client-side logs (like `console.log` in javascript).

I'm initializing the ChromeDriver and setting the logging preference to Client:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.SetLoggingPreference(LogType.Client, LogLevel.All);
var webDriver = new ChromeDriver(options);
objectContainer.RegisterInstanceAs<IWebDriver>(webDriver);
```

However, when I try to retrieve the AvailableLogTypes:

```
var whatever = driver.Manage().Logs.AvailableLogTypes;
```

`browser` and `driver` are the only available log types to read from:

[image]

When I try to get the Client logs:

```
var logs = driver.Manage().Logs.GetLog(LogType.Client);
```

I get an exception:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in WebDriver.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: unknown error: log type 'client' not found

Any idea how I can fix this? It seems like it defaults back to `browser` and `driver` logging at some point but I'm not sure where.

Comment: had you tried log type browser? please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36455533/c-sharp-selenium-access-browser-log

Comment: Yes, those are not the logs I'm looking for however.

Comment: if you want the output of `console.log` javascript calls, then `SetLoggingPreference(LogType.Browser, LogLevel.All)` is all what you need. Check out the article pointed by @derloopkat. Not sure what Client really means and if it's even supported by chrome.

Comment: @SimonMourier I checked the Browser logs and I don't see any console.log entries in there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want logs like `console.log()`, then I think `LogType.Browser` is what you need. Just make sure, the browser has those logs

If you don't see other `LogType`, like `CLIENT`, `SERVER`... you can try to enable those log types as the answer in [How to obtain native logger in Selenium WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13204820/how-to-obtain-native-logger-in-selenium-webdriver)

Comment: console.log() does not go into the Browser logs. I checked the logs for that logging type and I don't see any of the console logs. The answer you linked is in java and does not work for C#.

Comment: Actually, it does work! I just had to set the logging level to "All" for the browser: `options.SetLoggingPreference(LogType.Browser, LogLevel.All);`

Comment: @tnw, that was actually derloopkat suggestion (+ me insisting)... you're not giving the points to the one that deserves it (derloopkat).

Comment: @SimonMourier It wasn't added as an answer so I'm not sure what you'd like me to do. I already gave the comment a +1.